# Expo / React Native - Add clickable icon along with StackNavigator objects

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there a way to add a clickable icon along with StackNavigator objects?

This is a working code and it will show a "createBottomTabNavigator" with only one icon that will lead to "OtherScreen" on press.

```
const OtherStack = createStackNavigator({
    Other: OtherScreen,
});

OtherStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Other',
    tabBarIcon: ({
        focused
    }) => (
      <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name='archive' />
    ),
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    OtherStack
});
```

I would like to add a share icon to the same "createBottomTabNavigator" so it will be aligned with all other icons but I don't want it to lead to a different screen. I just want it to open a share dialog.

I can't find a solution for this. Is it possible at all? Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a button to the tab bar that doesn't lead to another screen by overriding `tabBarOnPress` for the route. Here's an example: https://snack.expo.io/@notbrent/playful-almond

The important part is here:

```
Placeholder: {
  screen: () => null,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
      // don't call default handler!
      alert('pressed placeholder!');
    },
  },
},
```